# Tkinter: Display an image on top of other

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do a game based on Mario, and I wanna first, print 2 images on the screen with the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
janela = Tk()

janela.geometry("1920x1080")
janela.title("Mario")

mario = PhotoImage(file = "cenario.png")

label = Label(janela, image = mario).place(x=0,y=0)
photo = PhotoImage(file = "mario.png")
label = Label(janela, image = photo).place(x=3,y=600)

janela.mainloop()
```

And what I get was: 
[image: Mario's image is transparent, but the background is displayed gray]

How can I display without this grey background?

Thank you

Comment: Read this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53047086/7414759)

Comment: I tried Reading this question, but I can't understand. I'm new on tkinter...