# How can I make a transparent background in tkinter using canvas?

Tags: image, canvas, tkinter, transparent

I need the background of the photo to be transparent; below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.configure(bg="yellow")
image=Image.open("zombie.png")
image=image.resize((50,50))
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canvas=Canvas(width=150, height=100,borderwidth=3,bd=0)
canvas.create_image(50,50,image=img)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a tkinter canvas background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021603/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-background-transparent)

Comment: tkinter canvas cannot has transparent background.  Can you use the canvas as the background (instead of `root`) and put transparent PNG images on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021603/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-background-transparent) for a more detailed explanation of making transparent background. This could be a starting point.

Comment: It said in the link that setting `bg=''` will raise error.