# Tkinter Canvas without white background (make it transparent)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hi I'm trying to make a canvas to create images onto it, but when I create the canvas, it has this ugly white background.

```
test_canvas = Canvas(main_window,100,100, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

And after placing it, it has a white background.

Is there anyway to remove that background and make it blend in (be transparent)?

**Here's an image to see the problem (I want that white background to disappear and blend in with the rest of the background)**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15fib.jpg

Comment: Did you try `Canvas(...,bg="",...)`?

Comment: here is a similar question on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021603/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-background-transparent  --  do you find it helpful?

Comment: bg='' attribute returns an error _tkinter.TclError: unknown color name ""

Comment: That SO thread doesn't help me unfortunately

Comment: @Aleksas are you a windows user and want to create a windows application?

Comment: Yes, I'm mainly porting this app to windows,  idc about other OSes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **windows only solution** is to use the [pywin32 modul](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) and can be installed with:

> pip install pywin32

With pywin32 you can alter the window [exstyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) and set the canvas to a [layered window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows). A [layered window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) can have a transparent colorkey and is done like in the exampel below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
        

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='yellow')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='#000000')#full black
hwnd = canvas.winfo_id()
colorkey = win32api.RGB(0,0,0) #full black in COLORREF structure
wnd_exstyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
new_exstyle = wnd_exstyle | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd,win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,new_exstyle)
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd,colorkey,255,win32con.LWA_COLORKEY)
canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100,fill='blue')
canvas.pack()
```

NOTE: AFTER DEFINING A TRANSPARENT COLORKEY EVERYTHING IN THAT CANVAS WITH THAT COLOR WILL BE TRANSPARENT!

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at your solution and try, thanks for providing this.

Comment: Well I'll be damned! It works, no idea how, but who cares LOL, thank you very much dude.

Comment: @Aleksas I posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70150296/13629335) with a little more information.