# (Tkinter) Making a frame transparent without making the whole window transparent

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label that is the background image and a frame on that label that shows other images and buttons, but I have some white spaces. Is it possible to make those spaces transparent to show the background image?

I've tried making the background a color and making that color transparent with:

```
window.attributes("-transparentcolor", "#20fc03");

frame.configure(background="20fc03");
```

but it makes the whole window transparent showing my desktop.

I can provide code if needed, I just do not know what would be useful.

Comment: I know at least a Windows specific solution for it, [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021603/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-background-transparent/70150296#70150296)

Comment: Use `Canvas`: `create_image(...)` to show images and `create_window(...)` to put buttons into the canvas.