# Make the Canvas element in a tkinert app to be fully transparent?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=window_width, height=window_height, bg=None, bd=0)
```

I tried setting the background to None, but it didn't do anything. I also tried reading various articles too see if that could help fix my problem as well, but to no avail, it didn't work.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70150296/13629335

Comment: Perhaps a philosophical question but: a _fully_ transparent canvas is invisible, so can you just remove the canvas? The result is the same.

Comment: You want the canvas to be fully transparent so what do expect to see through or behind the canvas?